# Ansynchronous function in useEffect hook dependancy array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks, frontend

Can we pass an asynchronous function (example fetchData() ) in a dependancy array of useEffect of a react component ? example :
`useEffect(()=>{fetchData().then(data=>{ //do something with data like setting state`
)}},[fetchData])

Answer (score 1):

yes for sure but you need to pass empty dependency to avoid overlapping or pass an state array dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchMyAPI() {
      let response = await fetch('api/data')
      response = await response.json()
      dataSet(response)
    }
    fetchMyAPI()
}, [])
```

Comment: Thank you for answering , but i mean,  in your example above , can we put fetchMyApi in the dependancy array like this :




useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchMyAPI() {
      let response = await fetch('api/data')
      response = await response.json()
      dataSet(response)
    }
    fetchMyAPI()
}, [fetchMyAPI]) 

Can you give me a reference to a docs or something. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes sure, this is a great place to start it's will help in all of your questions https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is fine. Just be aware that a new, potentially overlapping, request will be made every time fetchData changes. If you only want to make this request once use an empty dependency array.

Comment: Thank you for answering , but that doesn't help , my question is if putting the name of an async function (fetchData in my example which is called as an effect) in the dependancy array of useEffect  is possible or not and why .Thank you in advance .

Comment: Try it! It is fine to put it in there. Async closures are not special in any way that prevents them from being compared by the `useEffect` function to see if they' ve cahgned. All use effect does is compare each thing in the array to what it saw last time with the `===` operator.